# Terraform Azure Backend issue

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

We are using Azure as the backend for our Terraform code. Below is the code.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.40.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "test"
    storage_account_name = "test"
    container_name       = "test"
    key                  = "test.tfstate"
    tenant_id            =  "abc"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias               = "new-new"
  subscription_id     = var.another_subscription
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

And I have logged in as a Service Principal user using the below command:

```
az login --service-principal -t tenant-id-here -u object-id-of-sp -p client-secret-of-sp
```

And when I do `terraform init` it gives below error:

```
Initializing the backend...
╷

    │ Error: Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).
    │ 
    │ To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'
    │ auth method - instructions for which can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret
    │ 
    │ Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.
```

Comment: Do you have a `provider` block defined somewhere in your code? If so, please add that to the question.

Comment: I think you might need to perform the steps defined here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform.

Comment: Yeah I already checked that documentation and logged in as an Service Principal user

Comment: Why do you have two `provider` blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
Initializing the backend...
    │ Error: Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal). │
```

I also tried to store the backend configuration file after I logged in to `Az` using a `Service Principal`, but I'm still encountering the same error.

[image]

To resolve the issue, you need to provide the `client_id`, `client_secret`, `subscription_id`, and `tenant_id` of the service principal in the `backend` block of your Terraform configuration

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.40.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "venkat"
    storage_account_name = "venkat123"
    container_name       = "test1"
    key                  = "test.tfstate"
    tenant_id            = ""
    client_id            = ""
    client_secret        = ""
    subscription_id      = ""
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias               = "new-new"
  subscription_id     = ""
}
```

**Terraform init**

Once I ran the `terraform init`, it is working, and the `.tfstate` file is also copied to the `storage account` as shown below.

[image]