# Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Code="ContainerNotFound"

Tags: terraform, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, gitops

During a Git-Ops execution using terraform script, always getting bellow error.

```
Initializing the backend...
Initializing modules...
- application in modules/app-service
- application-insights in modules/application-insights
- cosmosdb-mongodb in modules/cosmosdb-mongodb
- key-vault in modules/key-vault
- redis in modules/redis
- storage-blob in modules/storage-blob
╷
│    Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure 
     responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: 
     Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ContainerNotFound" Message="The 
     specified container does not exist.\nRequestId:3d028e99-601e-0063-7325- 
     0b834d000000\nTime:2023-10-30T11:39:20.9706758Z"
```

I try run to all the recommended fixed like `"terraform init" with either the "-reconfigure" or "-migrate-state" flags`

**Cli Response:** Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

Terraform config

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.72.0"
    }
    azurecaf = {
      source  = "aztfmod/azurecaf"
      version = "1.2.26"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {    
    resource_group_name  = "rg-cloud-sample-us"
    storage_account_name = "st001sampleus"
    container_name       = "sample-container-us-1"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    access_key           = "Je8/L4LapIu7htf+4vrKbTG6+AStiCC0Jw=="
    
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id      = "********"
  features {}
}
```

I give all the recommended premising like contributor, owner, Storage Blob Data Contributor / Owner , but nothing work as expected.

Need a solution to resolve this issue!!! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @VinayB: double check it, seems everything is correct !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **gitops action template** I am using, **Container name** hard coded as `tfsate`

So if I use the bellow configuration it is working as expected.

```
    terraform {
     required_providers {
      azurerm = {
       source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
       version = "3.72.0"
    }
    azurecaf = {
      source  = "aztfmod/azurecaf"
      version = "1.2.26"
    }
   }

   backend "azurerm" {    
     resource_group_name  = "rg-cloud-sample-us"
     storage_account_name = "st001sampleus"
     container_name       = "tfstate"
     key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
     access_key           = "Je8/L4LapIu7htf+4vrKbTG6+AStiCC0Jw=="
    
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id      = "********"
  features {}
}
```

**Note:** Actual issue is in the gitops action template code, if it is take the container name dynamically from backend configuration. It should work as expected. But for that we need to change in the action template code. So for now if I use `tfsate` as a container name, it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure 
     responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error
```

The error message you're encountering indicates that the specified container does not exist in the specified storage account. There is no issue with permissions, as being a `contributor` should be sufficient to upload a file to `Azure Blob storage`

I have contributor role on `subscription` level and uploaded `Terraform` backend file to `Azure Blob`.

```json
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "3.72.0"
        }
      }
    
      backend "azurerm" {    
        resource_group_name  = "venkat"
        storage_account_name = "venkatdemo"
        container_name       = "venkat"
        key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
        access_key           = "sfetNjI1uvkWFCjZ+zAkR5OV1nxqvngjgoLneI4EdBGT7rCZIqFk+NxtPLUePv3taifhRThuNB1+AStjU+zYw=="
        
    }
    }
```

**Terraform init**
Once I ran the  `terraform init`, the  `.tfstate`  file has been uploaded to   `storage account`  as shown below.

[image]

Refer: [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76992455/terraform-azure-backend-issue/76993459#76993459) related to same issue answered by me